# Firebase Storage – getting static link based on filename

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a situation where in Firebase Storage users store their avatar to `/users/{uid}.jpg`

If I then use the Storage API to get the download URL and display the image, it ends up being very slow to make the first request because the download URL is not cached anywhere.

So my solution is to get the DownloadURL when the user uploads the image and store that in Firebase allowing the client image provider to automatically cache the image which speeds up loads considerably.

However, there is one problem with this solution.

If a user replaces their avatar, the old link becomes broken instead of updated. I believe this is because a new token is generated each time something is uploaded for security reasons but these are of no benefit to me.

So my question is twofold:

1) How can I allow a user to upload an avatar to a path that is dedicated to them such as `/users/{uid}.jpg`, get a bare download URL that can be cached by the client, and have that URL remain the same even when the file changes at `/users/{uid}.jpg`

2) If this is not possible, what is the normal way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Download URLs are opaque.  The contents of the actual URL itself is an implementation detail of the system, and it's not supported to dig around in its contents.  The URLs can't be dissected or composed.

You can use a [storage trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) with Cloud Functions to automatically generate a signed URL whenever something changes in your storage bucket.

Comment: Yes, but then I cannot push the new URL to all messages posted by that one person. It would be too expensive. If I do not store the avatar URL with each message I still have to poll for the avatar URL by UID which adds considerable lag when loading images in a list view. But if I attach the download URL to the message they get cached by my image provider and will load instantly without any fuss. If it is true that I cannot get a static download URL based on filename/bucket/path alone, then it would seem I would have to cache the avatar URLs client side manually with some kind of ttl.

Comment: It sounds like you're going to have to accept some amount of inefficiency in your system. You get to decide which one.

Answer (score 0):

So instead of serving from a hard-coded URL, simply retrieve the URL from an updated value in the datastore (or any data storage system). Every time the user updates the avatar, simply store the new URL in the datastore and you can query for it when you need it.

Comment: This still adds a step of querying for the value which slows down the performance considerably in a list view.

Comment: Yes correct. You can further mitigate the performance issue by using [memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/). How often will the avatar change? If it's a common thing (like if you have an option where the user can test the avatars), then simply store the value in memcache or even a local variable in your code before finalizing and saving to Datastore.

Ultimately, the bottomline is you can't have a hardcode URL for the path because it changes when updated. Batched datastore writes should be relatively cheap if you don't expect a lot of avatar changes.

Comment: I'm using Firebase so I won't be using memcache.